# Azure Durable Functions Verbose Logging App Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-durable-functions

We have just started using an Azure Durable Orchestration Function which is linked to application insights.

The telemetry is filling up with logs we cannot seem to stop:

> Time  16:51:03 Message    funcname-applease: Starting lease renewal with
> token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  Category    DurableTask.AzureStorage
> EventId   123 ProcessId   8964
>
> Time  16:51:03 Message    funcname-applease: Lease renewal with token
> xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx succeeded Category DurableTask.AzureStorage
> EventId   124

We are getting 100s a minute and despite our Logging settings they are not stopping:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:04:59",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20
      }
    },
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information",
      "Function": "Information",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Information",
      "Host.Triggers.DurableTask": "Error",
      "DurableTask.AzureStorage": "Error",
      "DurableTask.Core": "Error"
    }
  }
}
```

These messages do not appear to have a LogLevel and despite setting all of these to none through to only error they still keep coming.

Does anyone know how to stop these logs?

Comment: in which table you're seeing these messages? trace table?

Comment: @user351711 Did you ever get resolution to this issue - I am seeing the same thing.  How to stop this verbose logging ?

Comment: No resolution I'm afraid, just have to live with it as the filters you set do not apply to Live Metrics, if you do find a solution please let me know but was told through Azure support no way to stop them.

Answer (score 0):

This message is from azure function app instead of function level.

The log level is to control the function, so it can not control the function app.